# How to highlight the respective tab on clicking an image in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few tabs each with an image in it. I can switch the tabs by clicking on the respective dots above it, or the image below.

The issue here is, when i switch the tabs by clicking the dots, the respective dot will be highlighted, but i'm unable to highlight the corresponding dot while switching tabs by clicking images.

Following the the HTML

```
<section class="main">
<section class="tabsblock">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="tab">
            <ul class="tabs clearfix">
                <li class="active"></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- tabs -->
            <div class="box visible">
                <div class="box-text">
                     <h3>TAB ====== 1</h3>

                    <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit aliquet felis, quis ultrices orci condiment.</p>
                </div>
                <img id="tab_1" src="http://s13.postimg.org/ywlkh7hon/tabs.png" width="437" height="459" alt="" />
            </div>
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-text">
                     <h3>TAB ====== 2</h3>

                    <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit aliquet felis, quis ultrices orci condiment.</p>
                </div>
                <img id="tab_2" src="http://s13.postimg.org/ywlkh7hon/tabs.png" width="437" height="459" alt="" />
            </div>
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-text">
                     <h3>TAB ====== 3</h3>

                    <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit aliquet felis, quis ultrices orci condiment.</p>
                </div>
                <img id="tab_3" src="http://s13.postimg.org/ywlkh7hon/tabs.png" width="437" height="459" alt="" />
            </div>
            <!-- box -->
        </div>
        <!-- tab -->
    </div>
    <!-- wrap -->
</section>
<!-- -->
```

And JS

```
$('.tabs').delegate('li:not(.active)', 'click', function () {
    $('.tabs').delegate('li:not(.active)','click',function(){$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').parents('.tab').find('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(250);
});
document.getElementById('tab_1').addEventListener('click', function () {  
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').parents('.tab').find('.box').hide().eq(1).fadeIn(250);  
});
document.getElementById('tab_2').addEventListener('click', function () {  
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').parents('.tab').find('.box').hide().eq(2).fadeIn(250);  
});
document.getElementById('tab_3').addEventListener('click', function () {  
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').parents('.tab').find('.box').hide().eq(0).fadeIn(250);  
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrico/nqB25/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code in the question, thank you.

Comment: link fiddle contains code

Comment: I know. That's why I'm saying "include the relevant part of your code in the question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using separate event handler for each image, You can use the following script in the respective click handlers of each image

```
$('.tabs li').removeClass('active').eq(1).addClass('active');
---------------------------------------^ index of the tab to be displayed.
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqB25/2/)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Tilwin, I really appreciate your time and effort.